# how to get a custom data value from a highlighted class element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to get a custom data value from a highlighted class element using jquery?
this does not work...

`$("#list li.highlight").attr("data-keyValue");` <--- is this possible with another syntax for this to work?

```
$('#list').append('<li data-keyValue= "' + list_keyValue + '">'  + list_dataValue + '</li>');

 .highlight
 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
 }
```

Comment: what version of jquery you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `data` as jquery converts uppercase to lower-case you have to use `data(keyvalue)` courtesy @Rob W

```
var list_keyValue="something";
var list_dataValue="asdasd";
$('#list').append('<li data-keyValue= "' + list_keyValue + '">'  + list_dataValue + '</li>');

$("#btn").click(function(){

alert($("li").data("keyvalue"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F7jDJ/3/

Comment: without the highlight, it works $("#list li").data("keyvalue");  with the highlight it does not work $("#list li.highlight").data("keyvalue");

Comment: sorry i could not understand you.

Answer (score 3):

It's recommended to use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) for this purpose:

```
var keyValue = $("#list li.highlight").data("keyvalue");
```

If the value can be converted (numbers, JSON, ...), the `keyValue` variable will hold the converted object. If you don't need this feature, stick to `.attr("data-keyvalue")`.

Comment: can you plz have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F7jDJ/2/ it doesn't work with `data-keyValue` but if its replace like `data-kv` it works http://jsfiddle.net/F7jDJ/1/

Comment: @EdithMacomber @3nigma JQuery converts uppercase attributes/tag names to lowercase names. Use `.data("keyvalue")`. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F7jDJ/4/**

Comment: ah! tnx alot for clarifying +1

Comment: if remove the highlight, it works $("#list li").data("keyvalue"); but I was hoping to track list items that are highlighted with the class highlight

Comment: @EdithMacomber Your Fiddle didn't have a `highlight` class attached. Also, I recommend to use `$("<li>").text(list_dataValue).attr('data-keyvalue').addClass('highlight').appendTo($('#list'))` instead of hard-coding HTML inside a JQuery string.